# Microsoft CRM Dynamics 2011 system jobs limit

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have  a workflow in CRM thats used to be calculating the age for the case . So  this workflow has a waiting condition y . the client has 700,000 cases ( number is increasing now around 5000/day ) . So , skipping closed cases , system will be minimum having 300,000 waiting jobs which I believe will send the system to a waiting state for all the system jobs .

I believe that somehow CRM 2011 has a limit for waiting jobs , I mean at specific point system will stop creating jobs/executing plugins/workflows until the waiting jobs is done . So , how to solve this issue ? and what is the limit for waiting jobs in CRM dynamics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a custom workflow activity that gets invoked by your workflow?
You can set the workflow to run once a day, invoking the custom workflow activity that will go through all the open cases.
In this way you will only have one system job per day.

Comment: Thank you , That is really better . However , do you know the limit for system jobs when crm doesnt create anymore jobs ?

Comment: I do not really believe there is a limit for those. They are stored in a database table like a normal Entity. There is a great deal of discussion about whether to remove completed jobs or not from that table due to performance implications when the table grows too much, so you probably don't want to have so many records there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's actually a limit on waiting system jobs, however I have noticed that the Async Service required more resources and is much less stable the more you have. We had an issue when we had over 10 million waiting (due to some bug, we suspect) and the service just refused to run until we cleared them all. So my suggestion is to not have too many waiting at anytime.